# Unhandled Promise rejection: timeout ; Zone: <root> in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, recaptcha, zone.js

When I use ng-recaptcha component while routing to another route.

Error is :

> Unhandled Promise rejection: timeout ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: timeout undefined

[image]

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: timeout Zone: <root>; Task: Promise. then; 
Value: timeout undefined
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</</api.onUnhandledError
handleUnhandledRejection
loop 1
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</</api.microtaskDrainDone
drainMicroTaskQueue
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneTask.invokeTask
ZoneTask/this.invoke
timer
```

How could I resolve this error?

Comment: Please provide a reproduce repo. This is just a normal error, when you have an uncaught error in promise.

Comment: @jialipassion repo produce impossible. this error how debug them ?

Comment: you can just add break point at `zone.js` 665, check the `error.rejection`.

Comment: this error can hide on console or not ?

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: @fxck not yet.!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52617979/recaptcha-v2-throws-an-error-when-it-is-reset-and-its-container-element-is-remov related

Comment: @fxck yes related i have used to recaptcha but it throw error when recaptha verifies  then 60 second after promise rejection throws

Comment: It would be helpful, if you could provide a reproduction on stackblitz or at least a working code snippet.